# Is it possible to invite users outside of the domain?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I am building a web app where, basically, one user can pay to meet another user in a Google Meet. This would then create a Google Meet Calendar Event where the two users + one user from the company would be invited to a video meeting.

Basically, domain is example.com. This email address (service account), must invite attendee1@companyX.com and attendee2@companyY.com. When I put the event with no attendee, no problemo. As soon as I put the other attendees, I get:

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "calendar", "reason": "forbiddenForServiceAccounts", "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority." } ], "code": 403, "message": "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority." } }
```

I want to use a service account since it's the company (example.com), it never changes and I don't want the website to break if the password/whatever changes.

Here is my code:

```
        $client = new Google\Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
            'summary' => 'Entretien vidéo',
            'start' => array(
              'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
              'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
            ),
            'end' => array(
              'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
              'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
            ),
            'recurrence' => array(
              'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
            ),
            'attendees' => [
              [
                'email' => "attendee@email.com"
              ]
            ],
            "conferenceData"=> [
              "createRequest" => [
                "conferenceSolutionKey"=> [
                  "type"=> "hangoutsMeet"
                ],
                "requestId"=> "7qxalsvy0exxaje"
              ]
            ],
          ));

          $calendarId = 'primary';
          $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
          printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);    });
```

Can anybody help me about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set up [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation) at all?

Answer (score 0):

To use the **Google Calendar** with your domain you need [sign up](https://google.com/a/signup) for Gsuite

see  https://support.google.com/a/answer/39410?hl=en

Prices plans:  https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247360?hl=en